# How to add <link> tags in <head > for prefetch & preload in VF page

Tags: visualforce

I need to add bunch of  tags in head of the visual force page. Currently the only way possible is to use `<apex:stylesheet />` . but that is specific to stylesheets. I need a link tag to prefetch fonts and some heavy images.

Is there a way to get this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you need to retain the look and feel of Salesforce for your page, writing to the head when Visualforce is generating your HTML isn't really possible. You can get closer by using a script to inject some tags into the `head` when the `body` starts to execute, but this is obviously not ideal.

If you do not need the SF header or look/feel you can set `applyHtmlTag` to false on your `<apex:page>` opening tag and then get full access to write a complete HTML page including defining the `head`.